# How to generate an entropy using crypto/rand

Tags: go, random, entropy

I am trying to generate an entropy using crypto/rand instead of math/rand, and my entropy needs to be of type io.Reader.

```
//using math/rand

src := mathrand.NewSource(123)
entropy := mathrand.New(src)
```

I would appreciate all the suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

It's right at the top of the package doc: https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/rand#pkg-variables

> Reader is a global, shared instance of a cryptographically secure random number generator.

Just use `rand.Reader`.